# how to write sensor's libraries from scratch

Tags: embedded, stm32, sensors

Can someone explain to me how can I write sensor's library from zero, I read the datasheet, and some Arduino libraries but I did not understand how they had written them

Comment: ***`libraries but I did not understand how they had written them`*** Then it is far too early for you. Learn C or C++, code, exercise and understanding will come with time. There is no other way.

Comment: I already know c and c++, but for example how to read temprature from a sensor (dht or sht) i want to learn how to write those functions by myself

Comment: ***`I already know c and c++`*** then you should not have any problems to understand those libraries. If you do not understand - then you do not know `C` or `C++` good enough (Arduino libraries a quite simple and it is enough to know language on the very basic level to understand them)

Answer (score 3):

It's not a trivial task to write a library for embedded projects. Most of the times, it's almost impossible to write a completely generic one that can satisfy everyone's needs.

Don't let Arduino library examples fool you. Most of them are not designed and optimized for real world applications with strict timing constraints. They are useful when reading that sensor is the only thing your embedded system does. You can also use them sequentially in a master loop when blocking read operations are not a concern.

Complex embedded applications don't fit into this scheme. Most of the time, you need to execute more than one task at the same time, and you use interrupts and DMA to handle your sensor streams. Sometimes you need to use an RTOS. Timing constrains can be satisfied by using the advanced capabilities of STM32 Timer modules.

Connecting timers, DMAs, interrupts and communication (or GPIO) modules together so that they can work in harmony is not easy (also add RTOS, if you use one), and it's almost impossible to generalize. Here is an list of examples that comes into my mind:

1. You need to allocate channels for DMA usage. You library must be aware of the channel usage of other libraries to avoid conflicts.
2. TIM modules are not the same. They may have different number of I/O pins. Some specific peripherals (like ADC) can be triggered by some TIM modules but not the others. There are constraints if you want to chain them, you can't just take one timer and connect it to some other one.
3. The library user may want to use DMAs or interrupts. Maybe even an RTOS. You need to create different API calls for all possible situations.
4. If you use RTOS, you must consider different flavors. Although the RTOS concepts are similar, their approaches to these concepts are not the same.
5. HW pin allocation is a problem. In Arduino libraries, library user just says "Use pins 1, 2, 3 for the SPI". You can't do this in a serious application. You need to use pins which are connected to hardware modules. But you also need to avoid conflicts with other modules.
6. Devices like STM32 have a clock tree, which affects the cloks of each peripheral module. Your library must be aware of the clock frequency of the module it uses. Low power modes can change these settings and break a library which isn't flexible for such changes. Some communication modules have more complicated timing settings, like the CAN Bus module for example, which needs a complex calculation for both bit rate and bit sampling position.
7. [And probably many more reasons...]

This is probably why the uC vendors provide offline configuration & code generation tools, like the CubeMX for STM32's. Personally I don't like them and I don't use them. But I must admit that I still use CubeMX GUI to determine HW pin allocations, even though I don't use the code it generates.

It's not all hopeless if you only want to create libraries for your own use and your own programming style. Because you can define constraints precisely from the start. I think creating libraries are easier in C++ compared to C. While working on different projects, you slowly create and accumulate your own code snippets and with some experience, these can evolve into easily configurable libraries. But don't expect someone else can benefit from them as much as you do.